# Spring: test handler method for controller: throwing specific exception, nested servlet exception expected?

Tags: java, spring, junit

In my controller test class, I'm attempting to check the values of various parameters in the http response, when I force a specifically defined exception to be thrown. 
However, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.my.exception.myServiceException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980)
...
Caused by: com.my.exception.myServiceException
```

myControllerTest.java:

```
@Test
public void testGetMethodException() throws Exception {
    when(myService.getMethod())
    .thenThrow(myServiceException.class);

     mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/method"))
           .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$._statusCode")
           .value(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString()));

 }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, an uncaught exception in an MVC controller produces a 500. You'll need to provide more detail about your code and configuration.

Comment: You are probably missing some configuration in your tests.

There are different ways to handle this, depending on the way you handle exceptions in your code and how you have configured mockMvc... 

Put here your mockMVC setup method and other related code so we can see what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

This have happen to me, looking at the stacktrace a mocked object was provoking a NullPointerException, I recommend looking at the end of your stacktrace.

For example:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.time.LocalDate.now(LocalDate.java:225)
    at cl.forkchile.api.service.ScheduleService.canBeOpen(ScheduleService.java:24)
...
```